# Does not show the lables in dual language website in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I need to have a dual language website which is developed by codeigniter.I make a folder in application/language by the name of english.I create a file which contain the keys and their translation in this folder its name is cms_lang.php.In controller I load it `$this->load->lang('cms','english')`.I have a header page in all my views in this page I do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function set_lang(nurl,lang){
  var curl=document.location.href;
  $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:nurl,
    data:"lang="+lang+"curl="+curl,
    success:function(data) {
      document.location.href=curl;
    }
  )
  });
}
</script>
```

In header I have two links for switching between languages:

```
<a href="" onclick="set_lang('<?php site_url('article_cont/change_lang')?>','en')">English</a>     

<a href="" onclick="set_lang('<?php site_url('article_cont/change_lang')?>','dr')">Dari</a>
```

in controller:

```
function change_lang(){
  $lang=$this->input->post('lang');
  $curl=$this->input->post('curl');
  $this->session->set_userdata('lang',$lang);
}
```

in view I have a form which I want to show its lables in two languages.I do this in view:

```
<?php $this->lange->line('art_title')?>
```

I translated the `art_title` key in cms_lang file but in view it does not show the english lable.Where is the problem?

Comment: you have missed `=` here `&curl"+curl,` . it should be `&curl="+curl,`

Comment: sorry it is my typing mistake.It is right in my code.Now I correct it

Comment: here also `success:function(data{document.location.href=curl;})` should be `success:function(data){document.location.href=curl;}`

Comment: I correct that but set_lang function does not pass data to change_lang in controller

Comment: comment all code in `change_lang()` and do this `print_r($this->input->post())` and post the result

Comment: mistake here also `data:"&la` it should be `data:"la` remove the first `&`

Comment: I do this but nothing happens

Comment: alteast update the question with all changes